# C# express 2010 creates exe with false ownership

Tags: c#

Im developing in a windows-domain with C# express 2010. Every time i compile the code the created .exe has not my user-ownership and it is blocked for the next run.

> Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\MyProgram.exe" to "bin\Debug\MyProgram.exe">

Is this a problem to be solved in windows or C# express?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that you've already got a copy of your application running? If that's the case, it's not going to be able to copy the executable...

Comment: In particular, what exactly leads you to believe that the ownership is incorrect?

Comment: And, BTW, the language is named "C#", not "CSharp".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: i´ve read it both ways. When the exe is blocked, i try to delete it manually and cant get it done because of the rights i dont have. If i look at the security-tab then the ownership is not mine

Comment: @typ1804: I could spell it "joe", but that wouldn't make it correct. And, not to be especially arrogant but, are you kidding me? I've been developing in C# since 2001. And you?

Comment: @JohnSaunders geez...whats your problem. i´m here for a possible solution and not for a unnecessary lecture in spelling

Comment: With respect to the name of the language, I have given you a solution. Yet you challenge my solution without any proof. Doesn't put me in a better mood...

Comment: what solution? i explained my suspition in the ownership

Comment: Sometimes my visual studio locks files and requires a restart. In such cases I use http://lockhunter.com/ to obtain processes that are locking a specific file. Besides the ownership this might be a further issue which I would check. (If lockhunter is nothing for you, use ProcExp and search for the file you mentioned)

Comment: @samuel i tried indeed lockhunter and the blocking process is SYSTEM and i cant unlock it

Comment: I meant only that I have corrected your spelling, yet you respond that you have "seen it spelled both ways". You have not seen it spelled that way from Microsoft. And apparently, you haven't actually seen a difference in ownership. You appear to have imagined both things. I strongly recommend you go back to the facts in both cases.

Comment: @JohnSaunders i guess you´re right. must have picked the false tobaco in the morning and now im halucinating. thanks for pointing me in the right direction. have a good one.

Comment: Were you able to verify Jon Skeet's suggestion and check in Task Manager whether the application is currently running while visual studio is trying to copy it?

Comment: Jep and nope. It´s not running anymore